# Django on Heroku - how can I get a celery worker to run correctly?

Tags: django, heroku, rabbitmq, celery

I am trying to deploy the simplest possible "hello world" celery configuration on heroku for my Django app.  My Procfile is as follows:

```
web: gunicorn myapp.wsgi
worker: celery -A myapp worker -l info -B -b amqp://XXXXX:XXXXX@red-thistle-3.bigwig.lshift.net:PPPP/XXXXX
```

This is the RABBITMQ_BIGWIG_RX_URL that I'm giving to the celery worker.  I have the corresponding RABBITMQ_BIGWIG_TX_URL in my settings file as the BROKER_URL.

If I use these broker URLs in my local dev environment, everything works fine and I can actually use the Heroku RabbitMQ system.  However, when I deploy my app to Heroku it isn't working.

Comment: Please post your logs here and make sure you have setup 2 dynos: one for web and another for worker.

Comment: "when I deploy my app to Heroku it isn't working" Any particular error message? what is the failure mode?

Answer (score 0):

This Procfile seems to work (although Celery is giving me memory leak issues).

```
web: gunicorn my_app.wsgi
celery: celery worker -A my_app -l info --beat -b amqp://XXXXXXXX:XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX@red-thistle-3.bigwig.lshift.net:PPPP/XXXXXXXXX
```